# Re-writing URL's with variables (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, url, variables, url-rewriting

The CMS I have created uses a variable called "filename" that's passed via the URL to generate pages.

My typical URL looks like this:

```
/index.php?filename=about.html
```

I would like to amend my URL's to look like this:

```
/about.html
```

Of course I would also like my URL when first visiting the page to look like this:

```
/index.html
```

(Replace `.php` with `.html`)

I'm new to using the `.htaccess` file but would really like to amend my URL's to look this way, I hope that's possible. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+.html)$ index.php?filename=$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

For example, if I run: `http://so.localhost/This-is-your-page.html` result of `var_dump($_GET);` is:

```
array (size=1)
  'filename' => string 'This-is-your-page.html' (length=22)
```

I hope I helped.